# Github developへマージしたいくつかのコミットをmasterブランチへマージしたいです！

Tags: github

タイトルそのままなのですが、、
Githubにて
Github developへマージしたいくつかのコミットをmasterブランチへマージしたいです！
masterブランチへ取り込みたいdevelopのコミットがいくつかあります。
ワークフローとしては以下のようなイメージと認識しています。
「developブランチで開発し、developブランチへマージした数個のコミットを、
今度は、masterへマージしたい」という感じ..

ただ、コマンド等なにを使用するのが最適かすぐにわからないため
教えていただける方がいましたらご教示をお願いしたいです。

Comment: masterへdevelopブランチをマージではだめで、特定のコミットだけをmasterに適用したいということでしょうか？

Comment: ローカルで実行する Git コマンドの操作方法が分からないのか、それとも GitHub の web ページ上での操作方法が分からないのかが曖昧です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の方法で解決しました。

1. developブランチにいる状態から Pull requestsタブ＞緑色のNew pull request
2. compare:developを選択した状態
3. base: masterを選択する＞create pull request